# Using enumerateObjectsAtIndexes or a for-loop to iterate through all indexes of an NSArray BEFORE a given index

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, iteration, nsrange, nsindexset

What's the most concise way to iterate through the indexes of an NSArray that occur before a given index? For example:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ @"animal" , @"vegetable" , @"mineral" , @"piano" ];

[myArray enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:@"all before index 2" options:nil 
    usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
           // this block will be peformed on @"animal" and @"vegetable"
    }];
```

Also, this should not loop at all if the given index is 0.

What's the most concise, elegant way to do this? So far I've only cobbled together clumsy multi-line answers that use annoying NSRanges and index sets. Is there a better way I'm overlooking?

Comment: Any number of ways to implement. Concise does not mean clear. Use what does the actual job well. Don't fight the framework. Iterating NSArray does not require use of that method. That method gives block usage which is great for things blocks are good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
index = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count] && i < index; ++i) {
   id currObj = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
   // Do your stuff on currObj;
}
```

Comment: Why is `i < [myArray count]` needed?

Comment: if index >= [myArray count] you are in trouble :)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ @"animal" , @"vegetable" , @"mineral" , @"piano" ];
NSUInteger stopIndex = 2;

[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx == stopIndex) {
        *stop = YES; // stop enumeration
    } else {
        // Do something ...
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    }
}];
```

Comment: This is a good one. Is there a way to do this without the if/else? Something like *stop = (idx == stopIndex) ? (return;) : NO;

Comment: @yourfriendzak: Not really. According to the documentation, you should only assign `YES` to `*stop`. And calling `return` from within a ternary operator is what I would call "obfuscate programming" :-)

Comment: That requirement is due to the concurrent enumeration offered by another variant of the enumeration method.

Answer (score 3):

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, idx)]     
                           options:0
                        usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

}];
```

Comment: Why `-1` in `NSMakeRange(-1, idx)`? Should't that be `0` ?

Comment: @yourfriendzak. also providing nil as argument for (NSEnumerationOption) options: will give you a type cast warning. So rather then giving a nil here, it better that you should provide 0 if you want to ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd go with a block-based enumeration as shown by [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586571/106435) or [yourfriendzak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586686/106435), the accepted answer by [giorashc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586544/106435) is probably the worst, as it doesn't provide a mutation guard.

I want to add a (correct) fast enumeration example

```
NSUInteger stopIndex = 2;
NSUInteger currentIndex = 0;
for (MyClass *obj in objArray) {
    if (currentIndex < stopIndex) {
        // do sth...
    } else {
        break;
    }
    ++currentIndex;      
}
```